# Troubleshoot a hung nmap scan?

Tags: freeze, nmap

I am attempting to scan a host with `nmap` and it appears the program is hung. The scan is 1 host, all IPv4 TCP and UDP ports. The host is running in a virtual machine, and the target is a live host on the internet (the target is aware of the testing).

The scan has been running for about two days now, and here's the output (the organization's info  has been cleansed):

```
$ sudo nmap -sU -sT -p 0-65535 portal.example.com

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-02-09 15:33 EST
sendto in send_ip_packet_sd: sendto(3, packet, 44, 0, 100.100.100.100, 16) => Network is unreachable
Offending packet: TCP 10.0.1.226:52765 > 100.100.100.100:443 S ttl=56 id=33749 iplen=44  seq=1386045975 win=1024 <mss 1460>
sendto in send_ip_packet_sd: sendto(3, packet, 28, 0, 100.100.100.100, 16) => Network is unreachable
Offending packet: UDP 10.0.1.226:52577 > 100.100.100.100:1872 ttl=52 id=58463 iplen=28
```

I got the *"Offending packet..."* message about 24 or 28 hours ago.

How do I troubleshoot the problems with nmap?

Answer (score 1):

Start a tcpdump on the host that is doing the scan. Once you see the "Network is unreachable" message stop the TCP dump and examine from the end backward.

You will likely see an ICMP message with a code of 0. It means that something like a router, a firewall, something, is telling you that it can't reach the destination because the "Network is unreachable."

If this occurs mid scan--you get some results then this message occurs--it means that there is likely some IDS in the middle that has detected the scan and is shutting it down (and quite nicely telling you).

If this happens at the start of the scan then it means the network can't be reached.